# MongoDB setup db script (project based NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, setup-deployment

I am setting up quite big project based on NodeJS and MongoDB. I though about some setup script for the database so that I could automate db cleaning, setting up collections, defining indexes, etc on updates. In classic SQL approach it's common to write *.sql file that could be run from shell... Is there some good equivalent to do it with Mongo?

I added NodeJS in the title because I also though it would be nice idea to add the script definition into "scripts" part in package.json file but it is not the main problem here. Also, if it helps I decided to use Mongoose as a main driver in the project...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb), the equivalent to a **sql** file is basically a **js** file.

See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) for more info.

And just a note: [mongoose](/questions/tagged/mongoose) is an [odm](/questions/tagged/odm), not a driver.

---

**Update**

Suppose we have the following script file

```
/**
 * script.js
 */

db.createCollection('test');
```

You can execute it in `mongo` shell this way:

```
mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/dbname ./script.js
```

If you need to specify a username and password, you can use **-u** and **-p** switches. (Read [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/) for more info.)

Comment: As for mongoose I know but wrote it because of hurry. As for js file, could you please provide some example of such file? Just a single collection definition (but remember that the script should work on multiple environments with different host/user/pass)...